# What is bucketBy equivalent in spark dataframe V2 API or Iceberg?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning, bucketing

We have Spark dataframe V1 API with bucketBy option.

```
df0.write
   .bucketBy(50, "userid")
   .saveAsTable("myHiveTable")
```

I don't see similar option in [DataFrameWriterV2 API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriterV2.html).

What is the equivalent to `bucketBy` in V2 or Iceberg?

I couldn't find any details on clustredBy/bucketBy in Spark documentation.